# why can't i call onClick attribute of a fragment's view

Tags: android, fragment

if i try that, i got this runtime error

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.chat.okitokichatchat, PID: 3365
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onShowDialog(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
```

why can't i call it? with onClick? and why the system try to call it from a parent like Activity?
and also i found the warning "cannot find declaration go to" in XML attribute
can you tell me why?

Comment: Please, post your layout code (at least for that view) and the kotlin/java code of how you handle the listener.

Comment: A method bound with the `onClick` xml attribute will always be searched on the activity hosting the fragment. You should implement that method there and execute the appropriate actions to let the fragment know it was called.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use `android:onClick` in a fragment layout, but that will definitly raise `IllegalStateException`, and here is the exception you got

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onShowDialog(View) in a parent 
or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
```

From the log, you try to add `android:onClick = onShowDialog` to one of your fragment layout views.

And the error is raised because, you can only use `android:onClick` in activity's layout; so it tries to find the method `onShowDialog(View view)` in the activity that is associated to this fragment, and it can't.

So, the possible solutions:

Don't use `android:onClick` with fragments, just use [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) programmatically instead by invoking a view's `setOnClickListener()`.

If you insist to do that, then you can add  `onShowDialog(View view)`  to a view in your fragment layout, but you need to define that method in your activity like below

```
public void onShowDialog(View view) {
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag... // get the fragment
    ((MyFragment) f).onShowDialog();
}
```

And then create `onShowDialog()` in your fragment.

Note: I am assuming that your fragment is named `MyFragment`